# Convert to NULL in case varchar in ssis

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

From the source csv file, I have `DailyTurnover` column which is `Int` though there were `\N` values which correspond to `NULL`.

The question is - how can I convert this `\N` values to `NULL` going to destination column using SSIS task which has `int` data type?

Comment: thanks. Can you show me sample ssis expression related to that? still familiarizing myself to expression.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this by adding a derived column that checks for `\N` and replaces it with a `NULL` int.

After your source item, add a Derived Column component. Change the "Derived Column" option to `Replace 'DailyTurnover'`, and enter this expression (untested):

```
[DailyTurnover] == "\\N" ? NULL(DT_WSTR) : [DailyTurnover]
```

Then map the derived column to the destination.

**EDIT**: `DT_I4` replaced with `DT_WSTR` in above expression based on error messages received by OP.

Comment: thanks. though I got this error message  'Error at DFD Report [Derived Column [128]]: The data types "DT_I4" and "DT_WSTR" are incompatible for binary operator "==". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator'

Comment: That would be then because what looks like an `int` is actually a `string` in your data source. Instead of `NULL(DT_I4)`, use `NULL(DT_WSTR)`. I'll update my answer.